# With Swift, how can I schedule a local notification right before my app is terminated?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have tried sending a local notification when my App willTerminate, but this does not seem to schedule my local notification.  Any thoughts on how I might make achieve this?

My current setup:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification), perform: { _ in
  sendLocalNotification()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You generally have no way of knowing when your app is about to be terminated. `UIApplication.willTerminateNotification` is usually not sent to you. Typically you go into the background, the app is suspended (frozen), and dies in its sleep (because the system needs the memory you're using). You should assume, therefore, that if the app goes into the background, it *might* be terminated, so if there is something to do, do it then, because if it *is* terminated you won't get any more code to run.

Comment: Thanks.  I was also looking into setting my local notification when my app enter the background, however, if the user goes back into the foreground I need to stop it.  The real question is how do I figure out what time to set the local notification so the user does not receive the notification when the app is in the background or in the foreground.

Comment: Well, your requirement here is a very weird one, so I can't help with that. I'm just explaining why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what your app is, and why you are trying to accomplish this, someone can recommend a solution that you haven't thought of.